# JQuery: Select all ids ending with specific name and change its siblings input button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to indicate that a text can't be sent just yet, showing a grey input submit button with the class `btn-primary`. Instead `btn-default` is a coloured input button.
However there are many textareas on one single site as my JQuery code should be used for both posting a new status and to comment several status entries (like in Facebook).

That's why posting a new status has an unique id called `status_textarea` and the comment textarea has an id like `comment_textarea39` for example. So there is always a number at the end of comment textareas. That's what my first problem is with my code:

```
$('[id$=_textarea]').on('click contextmenu keyup blur', function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val();   
    var button = $(this).parent().hasClass('btn-primary');
    button.val(123); // Test to find the input button

    if (text.length < 1) $(button).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary');
    else $(button).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
});
```

I can select my status textarea with this, but not my comment textarea(s) as these have an id at the end like I mentioned (example: `comment_textarea39`). So I need something like a wildcard selection that only searches for: **id ending with _textarea and ignores what the id is named after that**.

Then I also want to select the next input (nearest *after* "this" textaera) that has the class `btn-primary` to switch it to `btn-default`.

---

**EDIT**

HTML Example:

Status Post Textarea:

```
<form id="statusForm">
<input type="hidden" name="privacy" value="0" autocomplete="false">
<textarea id="status_textarea" name="text" style="min-height:55px"></textarea>
<input id="status" data-case="status" data-form="#statusForm" type="submit" class="modal-send mt15 mb15 btn btn-primary" value="Senden" autocomplete="false">
</form>
```

Comment Textarea:

```
<form id="commentForm82">
<textarea id="comment_textarea82" name="text" class="comment mb15" placeholder="Hier kommentieren..."></textarea>   
<input type="hidden" name="log_id" value="82" autocomplete="false">
<input id="comment" data-case="comment" data-form="#commentForm82" data-hide="1" data-hide-success="1" type="submit" class="modal-send pull-right btn btn-default" value="Senden">          
</form>
```

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: In the first case there is a hidden `input` do you want to change its class? which input's class has to be changed in the second case

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the HTML, I made a mistake in my code and the send button was outside the form. Because I'm working with ajax it still worked and I didn't noticed that. However I just need to find the closest input button that has the class `btn-primary` or `modal-send` also. This is the send button. @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) instead of [ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) as you have a dynamic part at the end of the id attribute

```
$('[id*=_textarea]')
```

Another better choice will be is to use a class selector, ie assign a common class like `textarea` to all the elements that needs to be selected then use

```
$('.textarea')
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to a class. Can you explain why I should rather use class than id, even when the id name is unique? Is this about loading time or something similiar? Now I just need to find out how to find the input button I'm searching for. Do you have a suggestion for that? I edited my question to show HTML example code.

Comment: A class selector is faster than the attribute selector that is why the class suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use a common class to bind events, i.e. add a class such as `yourClass` then you can use class selector

```
$(".yourClass").on('click contextmenu keyup blur', function(e) {
});
```

However, use [Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to bind events and `.find()` within the event handler to identify `input` instead of `hasClass()`

```
$('[id*=_textarea]').on('click contextmenu keyup blur', function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val();

    //Important: Notice Here
    //Use find as hasClass returns you true/false not element
    var button = $(this).parent().find('btn-primary');

    if (text.length < 1) {
        $(button).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary');
    } else {
        $(button).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default')
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to a class. Can you explain why I should rather use class than id, even when the id name is unique? Is this about loading time or something similiar? Yes, now I just need to find out how to find the input button I'm searching for. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: @Vaia, Class selector is faster and also you can associate event to unwanted elements

Answer (score 0):

for those more old-fashioned, just search each textarea for an id containing 'textarea', return it if it matches the pattern in MAP:

```
var theseTextAreas = $('textarea').map(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('id').indexOf('textarea') > -1)
    {
        return $(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be slower as to search for the class `textarea`? I just updated it to find the class textarea instead of the id as I found out classes are faster than ids.